# Query prepared but not executed

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading MySQL log (on LAMP), and it seems  that all of my queries are being prepared successfully, but not executed at all. Any ideas?

```php
$prep_stmt = "INSERT INTO Zaposleni (`idInstitucije`, `jmbg`, `ime`, `prezime`, `datumRodjenja`, `adresa`, `datumZaposlenja`, `zvanje`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if (!($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt))) {
    die("Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
}

$insert_stmt->bind_param('iissssss', $institucija, $jmbg, $ime, $prezime, $datum_rodjenja, $adresa, $datum_zaposlenja, $zvanje);
$succ = $insert_stmt->execute(); // forcing query...
if (!$succ) {
    header('Location: ../error.php?err=Neuspesna registracija (unos zaposlenog nije uspeo)');
}
$insert_stmt->close();
```

And log:

```
63 Prepare  SELECT idZaposlenog FROM KorisnikSistema WHERE korisnickoIme = ? LIMIT 1
63 Prepare  INSERT INTO Zaposleni (`idInstitucije`, `jmbg`, `ime`, `prezime`, `datumRodjenja`, `adresa`, `datumZaposlenja`, `zvanje`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
63 Close stmt   
63 Prepare  SELECT MAX(idZaposlenog) FROM Zaposleni
63 Close stmt   
63 Close stmt   
63 Prepare  INSERT INTO KorisnikSistema (`idZaposlenog`, `korisnickoIme`, `lozinka`, `pravaPristupa`, `dodatak`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
63 Close stmt
```

Comment: Statements are closed at the end of the script in the clean-up fase, so the close in the log isn't necessarily the close-call in your code. That means that the script may have died somewhere halfway.

Comment: The amount of params exceed the amount of question marks by 3, this will cause this query to fail. Params and placeholders need to be equal.